# Vue-material stepper : keep input data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

I made a multi-step form with vue-material stepper :

```
<form method="post" class="enqueteForm">
    <md-stepper md-vertical @completed="onSubmit">
      <md-step md-label="Etape 1/5" md-message="Vos coordonnées"
        md-button-continue="Continuer"
        md-button-back="Revenir"
        :md-continue="step1valid">
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Civilite</label>
          <md-input id="civilite" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Nom</label>
          <md-input id="nom" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Prénom</label>
          <md-input id="prenom" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Email</label>
          <md-input id="email" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Téléphone (ex: 0472383254)</label>
          <md-input id="telephone" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
      </md-step>
```

The problem is when I valid the step 1 then I return, all input are empty, how can I keep input values when I change step ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I just need to bind my input with a v-model, sorry for the useless topic